# Angular - Property does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular, typescript, object, templates, properties

I'm having a few problems with Angular.

I'm trying to iterate through a JSON API but I'm receiving the message

> Property does not exist on type 'Object'.

Not exactly that, the error is

> Property 'sprints' does not exist on type 'Project'

I have this **HTML template**:

```
<mat-toolbar>
    <span>{{ currentProject.title }}</span>
</mat-toolbar>
<div class="data-panel">
  <mat-card>
    <mat-toolbar style="border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;">
              <span>Development</span>
          </mat-toolbar>
          <mat-card-content>
            <span>Access Code: {{ currentProject.accessCode }}</span>
            <div *ngFor="let sprint of currentProject.sprints">  <---- THIS IS WERE THE ERROR HAPPENS
              <span>{{ sprint }}</span>
            </div>
          </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

And my **JSON**:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "App Komputer",
    "description": "Website dedicated to computer related products",
    "accessCode": "5128",
    "createdAt": "2022-01-13T21:19:11.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-01-13T21:19:16.000Z",
    "sprints": [{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Sprint 1",
        "releaseDate": "2022-01-20T21:37:13.000Z",
        "description": "Specs up to 01/22/2022",
        "createdAt": "2022-01-13T21:37:58.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-12-13T01:46:36.000Z",
        "projectId": 1,
        "specifications": [{
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Add product button",
            "description": "New product button HTML",
            "duration": 10,
            "status": 1,
            "createdAt": "2021-12-23T01:46:36.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-12-23T01:46:36.000Z",
            "sprintId": 1
        }]
    }]
}
```

Also, this is my **Component**:

```js
constructor(
    private projectService: ProjectService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private _titleService: Title
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (!this.viewMode) {
      this.message = '';
      this.getProject(this.route.snapshot.params["id"]);
    }
  }

  getProject(id: string): void {
    this.projectService.get(id)
      .subscribe({
        next: (data) => {
          this.currentProject = data;
          console.log(data);
          this._titleService.setTitle(data.title+' · Scrumy');
        },
        error: (e) => console.error(e)
      });
  }
```

How can I fix this error? I've tried many things but none worked.

Thank you!

---

**EDIT 01/22/2022**

For those who asked, here's the complete scheme of **project-details-component.ts**, where I get the function from:

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProjectService } from 'src/app/services/project.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Project } from 'src/app/models/project.model';
import { Title } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { Moment } from 'moment';
import { EChartsOption } from 'echarts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project-details',
  templateUrl: './project-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project-details.component.css']
})
export class ProjectDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() viewMode = false;

  @Input() currentProject: Project = {
    title: '',
    description: '',
    accessCode: ''
  };
  
  message = '';

  constructor(
    private projectService: ProjectService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private _titleService: Title
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (!this.viewMode) {
      this.message = '';
      this.getProject(this.route.snapshot.params["id"]);
    }
  }

  getProject(id: string): void {
    this.projectService.get(id)
      .subscribe({
        next: (data) => {
          this.currentProject = data;
          console.log(data);
          this._titleService.setTitle(data.title+' · Scrumy');
        },
        error: (e) => console.error(e)
      });
  }

}
```

This is the **project.model.ts**:

```js
export class Project {
  id?: any;
  title?: string;
  description?: string;
  accessCode?: string;
  createdAt?: Date;
  updatedAt?: Date;
}
```

Comment: please also share projectService

Comment: Please share the `Project` class too. I believe `this.currentProject` is `Project` type.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing your JSON data and `Product` interface, you have missed out `sprints` property in your model.

Via [`json2ts`](http://json2ts.com/), your `Product` interface should be as below:

```js
export interface RootObject {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    accessCode: string;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;
    sprints: Sprint[];
}

export interface Sprint {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    releaseDate: Date;
    description: string;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;
    projectId: number;
    specifications: Specification[];
}

export interface Specification {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    duration: number;
    status: number;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;
    sprintId: number;
}
```

---

Another concern is the concern mentioned by @mat, as `currentProject` data is asynchronous. Either you have to **initialize the value to `currentProject`**:

```js
@Input() currentProject: Project = {
  title: '',
  description: '',
  accessCode: '',
  sprints: []
};
```

Or using [Typescript optional chaining (`?.`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html) to escape error when `currentProject` was `null` or `undefined`.

```js
@Input() currentProject: Project;
```

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <span>{{ currentProject?.title }}</span>
</mat-toolbar>
<div class="data-panel">
  <mat-card>
    <mat-toolbar style="border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;">
      <span>Development</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <mat-card-content>
      <span>Access Code: {{ currentProject?.accessCode }}</span>
      <div *ngFor="let sprint of currentProject?.sprints">
        <span>{{ sprint | json }}</span>
      </div>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zizc28)

Answer (score 0):

Don't you also get errors for `title` and `accessCode` properties? Because you are mixing synchronous code with asynchronous and that's usually causing the issue you are facing.

To explain, your template expects that the `currentProject` is immediately available, which is not true, because you load it from some service. And depending on how long will that take your template wants to draw data from `currentProject` but it was not yet initialized.

If you don't want to rewrite your code to use `async` pipe, either put the whole block to `*ngIf="!!currentProject", or add question marks before` currentProject` properties.

```html
<span>Access Code: {{ currentProject?.accessCode }}</span>
<div *ngFor="let sprint of currentProject?.sprints">
  <span>{{ sprint }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @mat.hudak! I don't get any errors from currentProject.title nor currentProject.accessCode. The problems begin when I try to iterate over the nested collection called "sprints", It should be for sprint in sprints, but that doesn't work :(